# Exception в main

Tags: java, исключения

Почему в методе `main` нужно писать `throws Exception`? Зачем это нужно? Кто примет исключение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`public static void main( String[] args )` - обычный метод, и кроме того, что вызывается виртуальной машиной для начала выполнения программы, может быть вызван из любого другого кода. На него распространяются обычные правила указания выбрасываемых проверяемых исключений (checked exceptions) после `throws`.

Поэтому если код в `main` может вызвать проверяемые исключения (например, вы читаете файл с помощью `Files.lines()` который может бросить `IOException`), компилятор *заставит* вас либо поймать исключение в `try-catch`, либо указать его в `throws`.

Указывать unchecked exceptions в `throws` не надо (и компилятор не требует). Можно указать unchecked exceptions, бросаемые явно (через `throw`) в методе, в его javadoc (параметр `@throws`).

В общем, `throws Exception` без явного требования компилятора - это экономия места в книге, лень или копипаста из другого кода. Хотите - пишите, не хотите - не пишите.

Теперь о том, кто ловит не пойманные исключения. Это экземпляр [`java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html). У каждого `Thread` может быть свой обработчик (задается через `setUncaughtExceptionHandler`, обрабатывает исключения, брошенные в этом процессе), либо можно установить обработчик по-умолчанию, через `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler`, который будет обрабатывать все необработанные исключения.

Код заменяет обработчик исключений текущего процесса (основной процесс программы):

```
public static void main( String[] arg ) {
    Thread.currentThread().setUncaughtExceptionHandler( new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
            System.out.printf( "Процесс %s не обработал исключение %s%n", t.getName(), e.getMessage() );
        }
    });

    throw new RuntimeException( "Исключение!" );
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Оператор `throws` показывает, что, возможно, при определенных условиях метод может кинуть исключение, которое должно быть обработано обработчиком `try-catch` вне зависимости будет брошено исключение или нет.
Так и в `main`, если же имеются непредусмотренные ошибки в коде какого-либо типа, то метод **обязательно** кинет исключение, а если же нет таковых, то метод спокойно завершит свою работу. Т.е `throws` - это предупреждение, что, возможно, в методе может быть выброшено исключение.
Ну и чтобы избегать ситуаций с выбросом исключений в главном методе `main`, сомнительные действия следует обрабатывать конструкцией `try-catch`.

К примеру, думаю, тебе известно, что делить на нуль нельзя, т.е данное действие не имеет смысла.
Поэтому, можно предположить, что если поделить на нуль, то будет выброшено исключение:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(1/0); // Пытаемся делить на нуль
}
```

Ну и вот из метода `main()` мы получили исключение

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero

Можно и предусмотреть, что, возможно, кривой пользователь обязательно захочет поделить на нуль, то мы просто это исключение обработаем:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try {
        System.out.println(1/0); // Пытаемся делить на нуль
    } catch(ArithmeticException exc) { System.out.println("На нуль делить нельзя"); }
}
```

Таким образом метод `main()` не выбросил исключение, так как конструкция `try-catch` поглотила `ArithmeticException` 
 
Да и кто тебе мешает использовать просто:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

}
```

Comment: Вот у меня и был вопрос- смысл в методе main делать throws, если и без него в консоль выведется ошибка. То есть если я напишу 5/0 без throws в методе main, то в консоли появится исключение. А могу обработать с помощью try-catch. Так какой смысл throws в main?

Comment: @Artem Zaichikov таким образом ты просто пугаешь, что возможно, где-то ты забыл обработать действие **1/0**. p.s деление на нуль - далеко не единственнtй вид исключений в java

Comment: Пугаю?) Я вот думаю, что это скорее напоминалка, чтобы не забыть, какие исключения есть. Как считаете?

Comment: @ArtemZaichikov :D неа. Это скорее, предупреждение, что в этом методе **может быть** выброшено исключение

Comment: Но ничего плохого, если я не напишу? Что с ним, что без него код не меняется

Comment: @ArtemZaichikov да)) только в будущем throws все-таки понадобится. Но ты знаешь, со временем, все станет на свои места))

Ну, и если ответ помог вам, то отметьте, пожалуйста, как правильный ответ, нажатием зеленой галочки

Comment: Надеюсь, что пойму. Спасибо вам